# Delete files with filename date older than 7 days

Tags: linux, files, delete

so all my files on my backup server are named archive-2021-03-18.zip, archive-2021-03-19.zip, etc. I want to set up a cronjob to delete files where the name is older than 7 days.

Would someone be able to assist me please?

Comment: It's trivial if you want to delete by file age rather than by file name ("delete files where the file was created or modified more than 7 days ago")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime || exit

cd /path/to/backups || exit

strftime -s oldest_to_keep archive-%F.zip $(( EPOCHSECONDS - 7 * 24*60*60 ))

rm -f archive-<->-<1-12>-<1-31>.zip(Ne['[[ $REPLY < $oldest_to_keep ]]'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could be done more elegantly but I'm just a simple person. Also this script will stumble on filenames containing new lines (which I've never encountered in my life):

```bsh
$ cat archive_cleaner.sh
#!  /bin/bash

age="7 days ago"

find . -iname 'archive*zip' | while read name; do
        bname=`basename "$name"`
        bdate=`echo "$bname" | sed 's/archive-//;s/.zip//'`
        agemax=`date -d "$age" +%s`   || exit 1
        agesrc=`date -d "$bdate" +%s` || exit 2
        if [ $agesrc -lt $agemax ]; then
                echo /bin/rm -v "$name"
        fi
done

$ pwd
/tmp/test

$ find . -type f
./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-08.zip
./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-07.zip
./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-10.zip
./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-14.zip
./1/2/3/archive-2021-03-19.zip
./1/2/3/archive-2021-03-18.zip

$ archive_cleaner.sh
/bin/rm -v ./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-08.zip
/bin/rm -v ./1/2/3/archive-2021-04-07.zip
/bin/rm -v ./1/2/3/archive-2021-03-19.zip
/bin/rm -v ./1/2/3/archive-2021-03-18.zip
```

Remove "echo " in line 11 to actually delete files.

Answer (score -2):

Please check the `find` command. While I'm using the actual file date here, the command has regular expression support in the list of files to search for, and should be able to do what you want to do.

```
# Find and delete files in the Daily tree more than four days old
# (rounding error means 4.23:59:59 is four days, so keep between three and five dailies)
find /dbdata/daily -mtime +3 -delete
```

Edit: While it's possible to do this by name, it's also much harder. We have to create a script loop that generates a string to represent today's date and the previous seven days, in the format that `find` (e.g.) wants, and then pass that to `find` with the `-not -regex` switches so that it will find everything but the files you want to keep.

Comment: That deletes by file age, not by file name as requested in the question

Comment: I think I did point that out in my answer. And that you could presumably create a regex that would do the name part. Me, I'd much rather use file dates rather than trying to handle formatting date strings and hoping that my format matched the filename formatter.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a solution which takes the filename date into account. You specifically give a "solution" which may absolutely break everything after a simple `touch -d "1 year ago" *`.

Comment: your edit part doing like that you said, it will delete all files except keeping those matched 7days date in their fileName. that's more worst that will delete unwanted files!